# Quando devo inativar ou excluir um registro? Boas práticas de banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-update, delete

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

**Quando devo inativar um registro?
Quando devo excluir um registro?**

No caso gostaria de uma dica de boas práticas, em quais tabelas compensa eu criar uma coluna STATUS? Sendo as tabelas que tiver essa coluna STATUS irei fazer um UPDATE para alterar a situação para ativo ou inativo e as que não tiverem essa coluna eu utilizarei o DELETE para deletar.

Tabelas que contém o meu banco mysql:
USUARIO, CLIENTE, COLABORADOR, FORNECEDOR, ORCAMENTO, ORDEM DE SERVICO, PEDIDO DE VENDA, PRODUTO, SERVICO.

Comment: Não existe boa prática, depende do que é relevante para o seu cliente. Se pra ele é importante manter um rastro ou histórico de itens removidos, nunca apague nada de nenhuma tabela.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 8):

## Remover Dados não é uma Prática Recomendada

A remoção de uma linha ou uma entidade raramente é simples. A operação afeta não somente os dados do modelo mas também a sua forma. É por isso que utilizamos chaves estrangeiras, para garantir que os itens de uma OrdemDeCompra não fiquem sem uma OrdemDeCompra associada. E esse é o caso mais simples. …

Quando trabalhamos com remoções lógicas, é fácil chegar em situações onde temos dados corrompidos já que a UltimaOrdem de um Cliente (uma simples otimização) poderá apontar para uma OrdemDeCompra que foi removida logicamente.

Digamos que nosso departamento de marketing decide remover um Produto do catálogo. Devemos então remover todas as Ordens de Compra que contém esse Produto? Devemos também remover todas as Faturas relacionadas a essas ordens? Indo mais além, devemos recalcular os lucros da empresa?

Que ninguém deixe ele fazer isso.

Na verdade, 'remover’' um Produto significa que ele será descontinuado. Nós não queremos mais vender essa linha de Produtos. Nós queremos nos livrar do estoque que temos e nunca mais comprar de nosso fornecedor. O produto não deverá aparecer em pesquisas de usuários, mas o pessoal do almoxarifado ainda tem que gerenciar esses itens. De qualquer forma é muito mais fácil dizer apenas 'remover'.

Ordens de compra não são removidas - elas são canceladas. Pode haver inclusive a incidência de alguma taxa se a ordem for cancelada muito tarde.

Colaboradores não são removidos - eles são demitidos (ou se aposentam). A rescisão também poderá ser tratada no sistema.

Vagas não são removidas - elas são preenchidas.

Em todos os casos devemos focar na tarefa que o usuário deseja executar ao invés da ação técnica que deverá ser executada em uma entidade. Em quase todas as situações, mais de uma entidade será levada em consideração.

O mais correto em todos os casos é a criação de um campo que permita saber em que estado a informação atual está, assim nunca será perdido nenhum dado, permitindo em um futuro ser analisado para alguma possível tomada de decisão.

**Dados são de extremo valor em qualquer negócio, principalmente os relacionados com TI, sempre os mantenha guardado.**

Comment: A não ser que você precise cumprir com políticas de segurança e privacidade de dados e seja obrigado por lei ou contrato a remover determinadas informações quando o usuário desejar. :S

Comment: Sim, nesses casos não há o que fazer e a deleção é a única alternativa.

Answer (score 8):

Para complementar o tema, gostaria de apontar algumas razões para se decidir por remover os dados do banco ao invés de desativar os respectivos registros:

- Um sistema onde os dados históricos representariam um volume inaceitável em termos de espaço ou desempenho e, portanto, precisam ser expurgados da tabela. Uma alternativa nesse caso é manter tabelas históricas ou mesmo confiar no backup.
- Evitar mais um nível de complexidade nos relacionamentos, pois é um custo adicional escrever em cada query ou junção uma cláusula para testar o estado do registro, fora o risco de se esquecer de fazer isso. Além disso, se a ideia é não permitir a perda de dados, **as alterações no banco de dados também deveriam sempre gerar novos registros**. Alguns cenários que lidam com dados históricos dessa natureza são bem complexos, tais como quando você precisa consultar registros e seus os relacionamentos em diferentes *momentos*.
- Segurança e privacidade muitas vezes exercem um papel importante sobre essa questão. Em muitos casos o usuário precisa ter uma função para expurgar definitivamente informações sigilosas, ou mesmo porque ele tem o direito de fazer isso. Nem sempre é uma funcionalidade disponibilizada diretamente para o usuário, mas muitas empresas tem inevitavelmente que implementar algum mecanismo para lidar com essa situação. Aqui no SO mesmo algumas vezes os usuários postam dados como senhas ou chaves privadas e os desenvolvedores precisam deletar a informação, algo que não é disponível para os usuários normais nem para os moderadores.

Concluindo, embora fosse ideal sempre manter todo o histórico dos dados, nem sempre isso é viável. Mesmo quando alguma implementação é feita via sistema, é sempre bom ter um sistema de backups confiável.